# Access value inside the ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to access variables (that has been initialized outside ajax success) inside the success function.

I have the following data:

```
<script>
    var num = 0;
    $('#colorsData').on('change',function(){
        var selected_color = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var selected_c_name = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var cat_id = $('#category_id :selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('getsize') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", _method:"POST", cat_id: cat_id, num: num},
            success:function(response){
               $('#append').append(response);               
                $('#demosize'+num).select2({placeholder: 'Select available sizes for this color'});
                $('#demosize'+num).on('change', function(){
                var selected_size = $(this).find(":selected").get().reduce((ob, el) => {
                    ob[el.value] = el.textContent;
                    return ob
                }, {});
                html = '<div class="row size-row" style="margin-top: 5px;"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><select class="form-control" name="color[]" id="sizesData"><option value="'+selected_color+'">'+selected_c_name+'</option></select></div><div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"><select class="form-control" name="size[]" id="sizesData'+num+'">';
                $.each(selected_size, function(key, value) {
                    html += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
                });
                html += '</select></div><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input type="number" placeholder="availability" name="stock[]" class="form-control h-100"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Selling price"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="discount[]" placeholder="discount"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"><span class="btn btn-xs text-danger removeCurrent"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></div></div>';                
                $('#appendDiv'+(num-2)).append(html);
                })                 
                num++;
            }
        })
    })
    $(document).on("click", ".removeCurrent", function() {
        $(this).closest('.size-row').remove();
    })
</script>
```

I want to access `selected_color` and `selected_c_name` inside the `html` variable. I thought of sending those value on ajax `data` but the response function returns html code. So my technique does not work there. How can I access the value that has been declared outside of the ajax success?

**My Html**

```
<div class="form-group div" id="appendDiv0">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
             <select name="imageColor[]" id="colorsData0" class="form-control selectebox">
                   <option>--Select any One--</option>
                   <option value="15">Aqua</option>
                   <option value="4">Black</option>
                   <option value="3">Blue</option>
                   <option value="22">Bubblegum Pink</option>
                   <option value="29">Capri Blue</option>
                   <option value="28">Cobalt</option>
                   <option value="19">Coral</option>
                   <option value="18">Coral rose</option>
                   <option value="26">Fuchsia</option>
                   <option value="34">Grape</option>
                   <option value="13">Green</option>
                   <option value="23">Hot Pink</option>
                   <option value="30">Jade</option>
                   <option value="33">Lavender</option>
                   <option value="32">Light Orchid</option>
                   <option value="20">Light Pink</option>
                   <option value="12">Lime</option>
                   <option value="7">Maroon</option>
                   <option value="35">Mint</option>
                   <option value="10">Navy blue</option>
                   <option value="14">Ocean blue</option>
                   <option value="6">Orange</option>
                   <option value="21">Pearl Pink</option>
                   <option value="8">Pink</option>
                   <option value="16">Plum</option>
                   <option value="17">Poppy red</option>
                   <option value="11">Purple</option>
                   <option value="1">Red</option>
                   <option value="9">Royal blue</option>
                   <option value="24">Shocking Pink</option>
                   <option value="31">Teal</option>
                   <option value="27">Tropic</option>
                   <option value="5">White</option>
                   <option value="25">Wine</option>
                   <option value="2">Yellow</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-1 col-sm-12">                
                <span class="btn btn-xs text-danger" id="removeColorDiv0"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>        
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
                <select name="" id="demosize0" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="405">Freesize</option>
                    <option value="406">XS</option>
                    <option value="407">S</option>
                    <option value="408">M</option>
                    <option value="409">L</option>
                    <option value="410">XL</option>
                    <option value="411">XXL</option>
              </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 903px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Freesize"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Freesize</li><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="row" id="firstFileUploader">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
                <div class="dropzone">
                    <div class="drop-upload" aria-disabled="false">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <a id="lfm" data-input="thumbnail0" data-preview="holder0" style="border: 1px dashed rgb(196, 198, 207); border-radius: 2px; width: 140px; height: 45px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; cursor: pointer; transition: border-color 0.3s ease 0s; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <img src="//laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lazada/lib/0.0.81/image/publish/IC_MediaCenter.png" style="position: relative;">
                                    <span class="upload-text" data-spm-anchor-id="0.0.p-30129.i2.81e84edfnX8IMm" style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; top: 10px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); width: 96px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin-left: 10px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Media Center</span>
                                </a>
                            </span>
                            <input id="thumbnail0" class="form-control hidden" type="text" name="image[]">
                            <span class="lfmholder" id="holder0" style="max-height:100px;margin-left:10px;display:flex"> </span>
                        </div>
                    <div class="medi">
                        <div class="file-upload">
                            <input type="file" class="files" name="images[]" multiple="">
                            <img src="//laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lazada/lib/0.0.81/image/publish/IC_upload.png" style="position: relative;top: 11px;height: 16px;width: 16px;margin-left: 8px;">
                            <span class="upload-text">Upload</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><p></p>
<div class="row size-row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control" name="color[]" id="sizesData">
         <option value=""></option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <select class="form-control" name="size[]" id="sizesData2">
                 <option value="405">Freesize</option>
              </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input type="number" placeholder="availability" name="stock[]" class="form-control h-100"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Selling price"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="discount[]" placeholder="discount"></div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"><span class="btn btn-xs text-danger removeCurrent"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></div>
</div></div>
```

I am trying to go with the other way. In my html there is `demosize0` now I want to get the selected value of `colorData0` from `demosize0`. How can that be achieve?

Comment: Did you tried printing that values inside success function and saw they should have values .Also what do you want to achieve..please elaborate.

Comment: @Swati Yes I tried printing the value but it gives the current selected value but while using it inside the success of ajax it gives the previous selected value.

Comment: what do you mean by previous selected ? when you are changing value ? please add that as well in your asked question

Comment: @Gaurav it should work. The `selected_color` and `selected_c_name` are outer variables in perspective to the ajax callback and will have access there. Something else would be your problem

Comment: @NithinChandran Can you please check my added `html`? and my edited question?

Answer (score -1):

You are have access to values of this variables from `success` function, try to use

```
alert("selected_color=" + selected_color);
```

in `success` function code, to show the value of this variables after getting the response from the backend!